# Routing Issue With FuelPHP

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelphp-routing

I'm using FuelPHP to create a simple web app with a photo gallery. All photos must belong to a gallery, and may only belong to one gallery. Given that a photo must exist as a component of a gallery, I want my URL structure to look something like the following:

To index all photos in gallery #4
`/admin/galleries/4/photos`

To edit photo 17 in gallery 2
`/admin/galleries/2/photos/edit/17`

...etc. Pretty obvious pattern. I added the following line to my `routes.php` to kick things off:

`admin/galleries/:gid/photos' => array('admin/photos/index')`

...but visiting `/admin/galleries/4/photos` gives me a 404. Thoughts? Is there another routing pattern I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would end up writing it:

```
// To edit photo 17 in gallery 2
'admin/galleries/(\d+)/photos/edit/(\d+)' => 'admin/photos/edit/$1/$2',

// To index all photos in gallery #4
'admin/galleries/(\d+)/photos' => 'admin/photos/index/$1',
```

That's assuming your controller is look something like this:

```
class Controller_Photos extends \Controller {
    public function action_index($gallery) {
    }

    public function action_edit($gallery, $photo) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how to create this link? use

```
\Uri::create
```

or

```
Router::get()
```